# Identify each virtual host running within a Servlet container

Tags: java, servlets, servletcontextlistener

When I have multiple instances of my Servlet-based web app running in a Servlet container, each instance for each of a few virtual hosts I defined, how can my code tell which instance is which?

For example, perhaps I have a virtual host for customers per state/province, say in California, another for customers in Texas, and another for customers in Florida. How does my Servlet code know which state it is meant to be serving?

I know how to save variables in the servlet’s context “attribute” key-value (`String`/`Object`) store. But how does each instance know what state/province-related info to put there?

Comment: Maybe you could use a application setting